# 'int' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python, I am trying to make a program that quizzes you on what note is on what fret of the guitar.

I've changed my code up some, but now the error says -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Documents\Games I have created\Python games\Guitar Memorization.py", line 107, in <module>
    print (guessing(string, question_type, correct, notes, guess, note, other_string, guessed))
  File "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Documents\Games I have created\Python games\Guitar Memorization.py", line 46, in guessing
    note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 248, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

How can I fix it now?

```
import random
import sys

string1 = {"E":0,"F":1,"G":3,"A":5,"B":7,"C":8,"D":10,"E":12}
string2 = {"A":0,"B":2,"C":3,"D":5,"E":7,"F":8,"G":10,"A":12}
string3 = {"D":0,"E":2,"F":3,"G":5,"A":7,"B":9,"C":10,"D":12}
string4 = {"G":0,"A":2,"B":4,"C":5,"D":7,"E":9,"F":10,"G":12}
string5 = {"B":0,"C":1,"D":3,"E":5,"F":6,"G":8,"A":10,"B":12}
string6 = {"E":0,"F":1,"G":3,"A":5,"B":7,"C":8,"D":10,"E":12}

string = random.randint(1,6)
question_type = random.randint(1,2)
correct = 0
notes = []
guess = 0
note = 0
other_string = {}
guessed = []
def guessing (string, question_type, correct, notes, guess, note, other_string, guessed):
    if question_type == 1:
        if string == 1:
            other_string = string1
            for key,value in string1.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the first string, where is the " + note + " note?")

        elif string == 2:
            other_string = string2
            for key,value in string2.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the second string, where is the " + note + " note?")

        elif string == 3:
            other_string = string3
            for key,value in string3.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the third string, where is the " + note + " note?")

        elif string == 4:
            other_string = string4
            for key,value in string4.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the fourth string, where is the " + note + " note?")

        elif string == 5:
            other_string = string5
            for key,value in string5.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the fifth string, where is the " + note + " note?")

        elif string == 6:
            other_string = string6
            for key,value in string6.items():
                notes.append(key)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the sixth string, where is the " + note + " note?")
    elif question_type == 2:
        if string == 1:
            other_string = string1
            for key,value in string1.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the first string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")

        elif string == 2:
            other_string = string2
            for key,value in string2.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the second string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")

        elif string == 3:
            other_string = string3
            for key,value in string3.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the third string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")

        elif string == 4:
            other_string = string4
            for key,value in string4.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the fourth string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")

        elif string == 5:
            other_string = string5
            for key,value in string5.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the fifth string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")

        elif string == 6:
            other_string = string6
            for key,value in string6.items():
                notes.append(value)
            note = random.choice(notes not in guessed)
            guess = input("On the sixth string, what note is at the " + str(note) + " fret?")
        guessed.append(note)
        return guess
while correct < 8:
    return guessing(string, question_type, correct, notes, guess, note, other_string, guessed)
    if guess == other_string[note]:
        print("Good Job.")
        correct +=1
    else:
        print("Not quite")
        return guessing()
else:
    print ("Good Job! You got all of the questions right!")
```

Thanks to everyone who is helping me out with this.

Comment: Try adding `global other_string` to the top of guessing()

Comment: the second thing to learn in python, after indenting, it's that "print() is your friend". So put `print(any_variable_you_want_see)` anywhere needed in your code. Learn to debug this way.

Comment: You're using `global`s? Too much duplication? Too many `if`/`elif`s where you should use a dictionary? Your dictionary keys aren't unique?

Comment: Most of the time, declaring six globals at the start of a function with no return value is an indication that you should rethink your program's structure. Also you've got a typo (not related to the error you're getting) on line 48, "`other_tring`".

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but the "first string" on a guitar is the high E, not the low E. The "second string" is the B string, "third" is the G string, etc. I would consider adjusting the 'string' variable names at the top to reflect the convention.

Comment: For the record `global`s should be kept to a minimum. Pass your variables to your function, get your function to do something with them and then return the result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `other_string` marked as global in guessing, so when you assign it to a string in `guessing()` it is creating a new variable `other_string` that is just in the scope of the `guessing()` function. To fix this, add `global other_string` to the top of `guesing()` to make your reassignment of it within `guessing()` visible at the global scope. Without this, `other_string` is still seen as an int in the global namespace, and ints cannot be subscripted .

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = {"E":0,"F":1,"G":3,"A":5,"B":7,"C":8,"D":10,"E":12}
string2 = {"A":0,"B":2,"C":3,"D":5,"E":7,"F":8,"G":10,"A":12}
string3 = {"D":0,"E":2,"F":3,"G":5,"A":7,"B":9,"C":10,"D":12}
string4 = {"G":0,"A":2,"B":4,"C":5,"D":7,"E":9,"F":10,"G":12}
string5 = {"B":0,"C":1,"D":3,"E":5,"F":6,"G":8,"A":10,"B":12}
string6 = {"E":0,"F":1,"G":3,"A":5,"B":7,"C":8,"D":10,"E":12}
```

1. When initilize `other_string`, use `other_string = {}` other than `other_string = 0`, this will tell you `other_string` is a dictionary, and you should only use it as `dictionary` other than any other data structures; the `other_string[note]` is an `int` value.
2. declare other_string as `global` in your `guessing()` method, then you can modify it in the body of `guessing()`
3. `print(guessing())` will not print anything, you did not return any value in your `guessing()` method,  you should add `return guess` at the end, and it should be aligned with the outer if-elif statement.

Comment: You still have one of the OP's problems - your dictionaries don't have unique keys. What are you expecting `string1['E']` to give you?

Comment: jonrsharpe thanks for point out that, you're absolutely correct. @Milikeye please read the above reply.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean by unique keys? I was expecting string1['E'] to give me 0 or 12

Comment: @Milikeye a dictionary can only hold one value for a given key (although that value could be e.g. a list), so adding `string1['E'] = 12` *displaces* the previous value (`0`).

Answer (score 0):

`other_string` is not an iterable object. You might initialize it as `other_string=[]`

Answer (score 0):

Although others have identified the specific error, I thought you might be interested to see an alternative implementation addressing the concerns I raised in my comment:

```
import random

class Guitar:

    NAMES = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third",
               4: "fourth", 5: "fifth", 6: "sixth"}

    STRINGS = {1: "E", 2: "B", 3: "G", 4: "D", 5: "A", 6: "E"}

    NOTES = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D",
             "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"] * 2

    FRETS = 12

    def play(self, guesses=8):
        while True:
            question = random.randrange(2)
            self.string = random.choice(self.STRINGS.keys())

            if question:
                answer = random.choice(self.NOTES)
                template = "On the {0} string, which fret is {1}? "
                valid_input = self.valid_fret
                checker = self.note_at_fret                
            else:
                answer = random.randint(0, self.FRETS)
                template = "On the {0} string, which note is fret {1}? "
                valid_input = self.valid_note
                checker = self.fret_of_note

            prompt = template.format(self.NAMES[self.string], answer) 
            for _ in range(guesses):
                if checker(valid_input(prompt)) == answer:
                    print("Correct!\n")
                    break
                print("Incorrect.")
            else:
                print("Out of guesses.\n")

    def valid_fret(self, prompt):
        while True:
            fret = input(prompt)
            try:
                fret = int(fret)
            except ValueError:
                print("Not a valid fret.")
            else:
                if fret in range(self.FRETS+1):
                    return fret
                print("Not a valid fret.")

    def valid_note(self, prompt):
        while True:
            note = input(prompt).upper()
            if note in self.NOTES:
                return note
            print("Not a valid note.")

    def note_at_fret(self, fret):
        return self.string_notes()[fret]

    def fret_of_note(self, note):
        return self.string_notes().index(note)

    def string_notes(self):
        open_string = self.STRINGS[self.string]
        return self.NOTES[self.NOTES.index(open_string):]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Guitar().play()
```

Note:

1. A class has been defined to hold the state required, removing the `global` variables;
2. Factored out the "magic number" 8 to an easy-to-understand argument;
3. Dictionaries, `str.format` and assignment of methods (e.g. `self.valid_note`) to local names (e.g. `valid_input`) have been used to reduce duplication;
4. Separate functions have broken the program up into smaller, easier-to-understand "chunks" of functionality;
5. Input validation has been added to prevent the user crashing the program;
6. Minimal data in variable names (e.g. `string1`, `string2` is bad practice that suggests that a list should have been used); and
7. No limitation on the notes/frets to be selected - it's all dealt with automatically.

You can even use sub-classing to easily test yourself on non-standard tunings:

```
class OpenG(Guitar):
    STRINGS = {1: "D", 2: "B", 3: "G", 4: "D", 5: "G", 6: "D"}


OpenG().play()
```